# Building graph without calculating explicitly all Edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im currenly trying to build a graph in js similar to this one:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

The edges should be the connection of all objects who share the same tags (one or multiple).

In the following Example these edges exist:

```
n1 - n2 (dog)
n1 - n4 (dog and cat)
n2 - n3 (fish)
n2 - n4 (dog and fish)
n3 - n4 (fish and reptile)
```

Example:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "n1",
        "tags": [
            "Dog",
            "Cat"
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name": "n2",
        "tags": [
            "Dog",
            "Fish"
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name": "n3",
        "tags": [
            "Fish",
            "Reptile"
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name": "n4",
        "tags": [
            "Dog",
            "Cat",
            "Fish",
            "Reptile"
        ]
    }, 
]
```

My question is now:

1. Do I have to calculate the edges for every object and every tag?
2. Is there a smart solution to calculate the tags without iterating through, with O(N^2) time?

There are over 500 Tags and much more objects, so the number of edges will be huge. Any advice is appreciated as I am new to js in general.

Comment: So you want to create a graph such that there is an edge between two objects if they have the same tag. And you are asking if you have to calculate the edges for every object? Unless I'm missing something, the answer should a big fat **YES**.

Comment: Maybe I made myself not clear enough. There is actually a two part question. The first one you have answered, the second one is, if there is a smart solution to calculate the tags without iterating through every O(N^2) times.

Comment: Build an associative array that maps tags to the nodes that contain them. o(n) to build this, then it's an O(1) lookup for each node to get the connections.